# Segmentation fault, when start modified binary code. MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, mips, elf, mips32

Now I'm writing a simple code crypter for MIPS32 binaries. Crypting is OK - it's simple, but when I want to inject the decrypter's code into crypted binary everything goes wrong. After the start, program exits with Segmentation fault Error.
I'm injecting code into the last section of the first LOAD segment - all the code injects after original code and data.
I've already made so to only inject command returning on the original code entry, but everythiing stays the same.
I've checked the address - it seems to be the right one.

Here is part of my code:

```
prepare_code(int* old_code_size, char *old_code, unsigned int original_entry, unsigned int code_entry)
{
    char* code = NULL;
    unsigned int add_code_size = 8;
    short diff = original_entry - (code_entry + *old_code_size);
    if( diff < 0x7fff);
    {
        int code_size = *old_code_size;
        code = realloc(old_code, code_size + add_code_size);

    //branch on original entry point
        code[code_size + 0] = 0x10; code[code_size + 1] = 0x00; code[code_size + 2] = (diff & 0xFF00) >> 8; code[code_size + 3] = diff & 0x00FF;
        code[code_size + 4] = 0x00; code[code_size + 5] = 0x20; code[code_size + 6] = 0x08; code[code_size + 7] = 0x25; //nop
        code[code_size + 8] = 0x00; code[code_size + 9] = 0x20; code[code_size + 10] = 0x08; code[code_size + 11] = 0x25;   //nop

        *old_code_size += add_code_size;
    }
    return code;
}
```

Strace log:

```
execve("./output", ["./output"], [/* 14 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9f9000
old_mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x77cc3000
uname({sys="Linux", node="debian-mips", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14227, ...}) = 0
old_mmap(NULL, 14227, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x77cbf000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/mips-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\2\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\10\0\0\0\1\0\1s\344\0\0\0004"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 760, SEEK_SET)                 = 760
read(3, "\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\1GNU\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\32", 32) = 32
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1636356, ...}) = 0
old_mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x77cbe000
old_mmap(NULL, 1621648, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x77b06000
mprotect(0x77c74000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
old_mmap(0x77c84000, 45056, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16e000) = 0x77c84000
old_mmap(0x77c8f000, 11920, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x77c8f000
close(3)                                = 0
old_mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x77cbd000
set_thread_area(0x77cc4490)             = 0
mprotect(0x77c84000, 36864, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0x77cc4000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0x77cbf000, 14227)               = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Anything will help!

Comment: The pointer for the `old_code` should be a pointer to a pointer if you want to realloc

Comment: I'm returning the result - it is not the point.
Everything is written in the result file, but it won't work well.

Comment: This is just a question, you `add_code_size` is 8 and when you `realloc` you add 20, then you increment `old_code_size` by 8?  is that corect?

Comment: Yeah it's ok. But Thank you, I've edit it. Everything stays the same.

Comment: wait so if you increase the `old_code` memory by 8 but you access values greater than 8 `code[code_size + 10]`, shouldn't the orignal `add_code_size` at decleration be 20  which later is added to `old_code_size`?

Comment: Seems like my head was too slow that time. This code, though it shouldn't, works fine and injects everything. Problem is that already built file won't work properly.